# Piping concat through gulp.src changes gulp.src glob

Tags: javascript, gulp

I'm still fairly new to gulp, so this might be a misunderstanding on my part.

I have gulp pipeline I'm trying to create that does something like this:

```
gulp.src('src/**/*.html')
    .pipe(html2js({some:options}))
    .pipe(concat('templates.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.src('src/**/*.js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/'))
```

When I run this however, the second glob does not catch all the .js files. If I run two separate piplines as:

```
gulp.src('src/**/*.html')
    .pipe(html2js({some:options}))
    .pipe(concat('template.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/'));

gulp.src(['src/**/*.js', 'build/template.js'])
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/'));
```

It works as expected. No errors appear to be thrown and in the first case, the template.js is added to the end of the file list as I would expect.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://github.com/wearefractal/vinyl-fs/issues/25

Comment: https://github.com/urish/gulp-add-src

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gulp.src accepts a glob and options so it can't handle the stream that's piped into it in your first sample script.

You may use an approach similar to your first one using [gulp-filter](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-filter):

```js
var filter = gulpFilter('**/*.html');
gulp.src(['src/**/*.html', 'src/**/*.js'])
    .pipe(filter)
    .pipe(html2js({some:options}))
    .pipe(concat('templates.js'))
    .pipe(filter.restore())
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/'))
```

Otherwise, following the lines of your second sample, you can use [merge-stream](https://www.npmjs.org/package/merge-stream) for merging the streams before uglifying:

```js
var merge = require('merge-stream');

var htmlStream = gulp.src('src/**/*.html')
    .pipe(html2js({some:options}))
    .pipe(concat('template.js'));

return merge(htmlStream, gulp.src('src/**/*.js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/'));
```

Comment: Doesn't gulp.src handle that now though, or at least as of gulp 3.8? https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#380 Or am I just using that functionality wrong somehow?

Comment: I didn't know about this: thanks for pointing it out. I'll have to give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

You should check out [gulp-merge](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-merge). It's designed to combine gulp pipelines:

```
var gulpMerge = require('gulp-merge');

gulp.task('build', function() {
    return gulpMerge(
        gulp.src('src/**/*.html')
            .pipe(html2js({some:options}))
            .pipe(concat('template.js')),

        gulp.src('src/**/*.js')
    )
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/'));
});
```

Comment: I hadn't thought of doing that, I'll see how that works, but it still doesn't answer the original question of why the glob changed it's match.

Comment: `gulp-merge` was apparently renamed to `merge2` in October 2014 and the old `gulp-merge` package was recently [yanked from npm](https://github.com/teambition/merge2/issues/5). This answer should be updated to recommend `merge2`, not `gulp-merge`.